# How would I add two mariadb servers to an existing pair and ensure replication

Tags: mariadb

I have a pair of mariadb servers running on CentOS 7, version 5.5.52.  Currently the Server 1 writes and reads and replicates to Server 2. I want to add two mariadb servers in AWS. I want one of these servers, Server 3, to read and write, I want it to replicate to Servers 1, 2 and 4; that is, I want replication to occur across all mariadb servers. I also want Server 1 to replicate to the other three.

Link to schematic:  https://www.flickr.com/photos/80050932@N06/51535391218/in/dateposted-public/

My question is, is this possible and thoughts on how to enable.

autossh is the tunnel that handles replication. Here is a line in

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/autossh.service
```

that may offer insight:

```
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -N -q -o "ServerAliveInterval=60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax=3" -p 22 -l replica Server1 -L 3305:127.0.0.1:3306 -i /root/.keys/replica
```

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Dual-Primary with two Replicas

```
R2 <- P1 <=> P3 -> R4
```

Plan B:  Use Galera and allow writing to all 3 (or 4) nodes.

Note:  Galera gives you easier HA, since the recovery after failure is better automated.

Potential problem:  Replicas (which includes all nodes in either Plan) reach out to their respective Primary.  You should verify whether a Replica on AWS can see your local Primary.  It may requires some help from `ssh`.  (Is that what you mean by `autossh`?)

5.5 is quite old; I recommend upgrading before embarking on this task.

All nodes in any replication topology should be the same main version (x.y, not necessarily x.y.z).  In some situations a difference of 1 may work.  (5.5 : 5.6 or 5.5 : 10.0).  MariaDB is already to 10.6.

Comment: great, rick james, thanks!